# Cache::remember с пагинацией и scopeSearch

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Добрый день всем!
В общем, понадобилось реализовать Поиск, пагинацию и кэш. Пришла и нагуглилась идея о том, что нужно бы отследить на какой мы странице, чтобы знать какой кэш кушать Вьюхе. Потом пришло понимание, что у меня есть ещё один параметр, который не учтён - поиск. Он реализован через scopeSearch. С ним урл становится иным(логично), принимает вот такой вид: .../products?s=iph&page=2.
Вопрос:: Как же всё-таки учесть доп параметр? По аналогии со страницами не вышло. Писал, что метод не тот и всё в таком роде
Собственно нынешняя реализация:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

$s = $request->input('s');
$products = Cache::remember('products-'.  \Request::input('page'), 1, function () use($s) {
return Product::latest()->search($s)->paginate(4);
;});

$acproducts = Cache::remember('products-'.  \Request::input('page'), 1, function () use($s) {
return Product::active()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
;});


    return view('products.index', compact('products','acproducts', 's'));

}
```

А вот вариант такого рода хотелось бы иметь:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

$s = $request->input('s');
$products = Cache::remember('products-'.  \Product::search('s')."&".Request::input('page'), 1, function () use($s) {
return Product::latest()->search($s)->paginate(4);
;});

$acproducts = Cache::remember('products-'.  \Request::input('page'), 1, function () use($s) {
return Product::active()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
;});




    return view('products.index', compact('products','acproducts', 's'));

}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

В поле key нужно было ввести вот эту строку

`products_p'. \Request::input('page') . '_s' . \Request::input('s')`

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cache_key = __FILE__.__LINE__.serialize($request->all());
    $products = Cache::remember('products-'. $cache_key , 1, function () use($s) {
        return Product::latest()->search($s)->paginate(4);
    });

    $acproducts = Cache::remember('acproducts-'.$cache_key , 1, function () use($s) {
        return Product::active()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    });
}
```